# composer-php fail to install laravel

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to move a laravel project to a remote server.
I just copy the folder on the public/html folder, then I've tried to install composer as described here:
https://getcomposer.org/download/

with the very first command I've seen this error:

> /federlegno$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" 
>   PHP Warning:  copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in Command line code on line 1
>   PHP Warning:  copy(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1
>   PHP Warning:  copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1

as solution I find to run the command without the https: `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`

and then it seems thats the others command works, without promt any error (I've tried even to visit the link with the browser and it works!).

Then when I try to run:

```
composer install
```

inside the laravel folder this error is raised:

> bash: composer: command not found

Some additional information:

> /federlegno$ php -r "phpinfo();" | grep OpenSSL SSL Version =>
>   OpenSSL/1.0.2r OpenSSL support => enabled OpenSSL Library Version =>
>   OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018 OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1a 
>   20 Nov 2018 Native OpenSSL support => enabled

php version:

```
ederlegno$ php -v PHP
7.2.15-1+0~20190209065123.16+stretch~1.gbp3ad8c0 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2019 06:51:24) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-1+0~20190209065123.16+stretch~1.gbp3ad8c0, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Laravel version 5.4

Comment: don't forget, on your prod box you should do `composer install --no-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `composer.phar` file (which is downloaded by the installation scripts) to the `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` directory

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

or

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```